# Display document in page viewer

Tags: 2010, page-viewer-web-part

Im struggling a bit with this.

I want to display a document on a page, being able to see our usual global and current navigation items. We know we should use the page viewer web part. 
The problem:
On selecting "File" from the options of what we want to display, microsoft says the following:

"File    Select this option to display the contents of a file. This option also displays the Browse button under the Link text box. The file opens either in a separate browser window or inside the Web Part if the application that opens the file supports inline activation for that file in the browser window."

We dont see a browse button.

This post seems to have a similar problem, but the difference for us is that we want to store the document in SharePoint AND display it on a different page. 
http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2007/11/29/displaying-a-file-or-a-folder-in-the-page-viewer.aspx

Also, when we enter a link we get red error text saying:

"The file name or path is not valid for the Link property. Check the spelling and syntax, and then type it again."

We do have Office Web Apps installed and functional, but in this instance it doesnt quite match our needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Browse button does not show for me either. If you enter a file reference in the Link box, you need to start it with the protocol handler `file://` instead of `http://`, for example

```
file://YourServer/YourPath/YourSite/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Test2.txt
```

If the file resides on a file share and not in SharePoint, you need:

```
file:/N:\Misc\Test2.pdf
```

where "N:" is a mapped drive, or

```
file://\\Server\folder1\folder\test2.pdf
```

For me this works for PDF and TXT files in the browser, DOCX and RTF open in Word.